# Delete dictionary from a list in class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, class-attributes

I have a list saved as a class attribute and I am trying to delete a specific dictionary in that list.

The project is a simple one, one where the user should be able to add items to a collection (saved in a list), edit them, filter search results by types (previously added to list) and delete dictionary entries from list.

Here is the constructor:

```
class Item:
    py_collection_list = []

    def __init__(self, item_name: str, item_type: str, date_add, dom, item_info: str):
        self.__id = Item.get_next_id()
        self.item_name: str = item_name
        self.item_type: str = item_type
        self.date_add = date_add
        self.dom = dom
        self.item_info: str = item_info
        Item.py_collection_list.append(self)
```

(`Item` being the super class and `py_collection_list` being the list)

I was able to create a filter with the following code:

```
def show_items():
    print('View items by type \nComputer | Camera | Phone | Video Player ')
    type_selection = input('Type> ')
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        if type_selection == i.item_type:
            print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
```

I used several options for the deletion and this is the latest one which isn't working:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
    remove_item = input("Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ")
    if remove_item == i.item_name:
        del [remove_item]
```

Comment: `Item.py_collection_list.remove(name)` or `Item.py_collection_list.pop(idx)`

Comment: Thank you for your reommendation. Unfortunately I received 2 errors: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list  and Item.py_collection_list.pop(remove_item)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Irrelevant but you're not appending dictionaries to your `list`. You're appending instances of `Item`.

Comment: You can either remove by value, or pop by index. In your case you would need to `remove(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `delete_item` method, you only check equality for the last element in your list.

Your `for` loop works by going through your `list` and assigning each value to `i`. After your `list` is exhausted and you've exited it, `i` still contains the last value it was assigned. That is the only element you check for equality with `remove_item`.

The easiest way to check for equality for all items and filter the ones that don't match would be a list comprehension.

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", 
                                                 "Item", 
                                                 "Date added", 
                                                 "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), 
                                                       i.item_name, 
                                                       i.date_add, 
                                                       i.dom))
    remove_item = input("Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection>")
    Item.py_collection_list = [i for i in Item.py_collection_list if i.item_name != remove_item]
```

This allows you to filter multiple entries in one shot and isn't committing an atrocity like mutating your list as you iterate.

Comment: THANK YOU so much!! this worked! I'm still getting my mind around python (newbie of 3 months), so I apologize for the committment of atrocity, but I really appreciate for you taking the time and helping me.